# Given that $X$ is a topological space and $X$ is Hausdorff, with $K_1$ and $K_2$ in $X$ being compact sets, show that their intersection is compact.

Tags: general-topology

This question requires me to prove that if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are two compact subsets of $X$, and $X$ is Hausdorff, then their intersection is compact in $X$. I know that in order to show that their intersection is compact, I must show that every cover has a finite subcover, but I'm not really sure how to proceed from there. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Hausdorff space, compact sets are closed. So $K_1\cap K_2$ is closed in $K_1$. Since a closed subset of a compact set is compact, you're finished.